# How to enable overlay scrollbars?

Tags: 11.04, overlay-scrollbars

I read that from Natty beta 2 overlay scrollbars are default, but my installation is a fully updated one that I installed from an alpha release.

I think the settings did not kick in from the update so I want to know how to enable it (there are plenty posts on how it disable it though)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Make sure you have the packages `overlay-scrollbar` and `liboverlay-scrollbar-0.1-0` installed. (It's possible that you somehow lost the package `ubuntu-desktop` which usually is responsible for pulling in such new packages.)
- Overlay scrollbars only work in a handful of applications right now (easiest to test are probably Nautilus and gedit), so maybe you have just tested the wrong applications.

Comment: thnx man! u were right, think the ubuntu-desktop package got removed when I removed evolution, so reinstalling it did the trick!