# enable overlay-scrollbar in xubuntu 12.10 (xfce 4.10)

Tags: 12.10, xfce, overlay-scrollbars

I just did a release upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10 and I noticed that even though I have the overlay-scrollbar package installed, it is not used. I have tried purging and reinstalling the package, but nothing has changed even after reboot (see screenshot).

What can I try to do to get the overlay-scrollbars working again?

[image: overlay-scrollbar is installed]

Comment: Which theme are you using?

Comment: Bluebird, however it's the same with any other theme that I've tried.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Bluebird has been replaced by Greybird. If you go into /usr/share/themes/theme_name/gtk-3.0/gtk.css or /usr/share/themes/theme_name/gtk-2.0/gtkrc and search for overlay, do you see a section on overlay scrollbars?

Comment: It's true that it has been replaced by Greybird, but I have used the very same theme on Xubuntu 12.04 (from git repository, which means that it hasn't been updated during this update) and the overlay scrollbars worked. I can't get any theme to show the overlay scrollbars in 12.10 so I don't think that this is theme-related.

Comment: See if these links help: [htorque](http://askubuntu.com/a/35234/25656) suggests that you need `liboverlay-scrollbar-0.1-0` though the version number may be different now; [Erigami](http://askubuntu.com/a/177160/25656) suggests editing `gsettings`.

Comment: Thanks, but in my dconf-editor I have `org.gnome.desktop.interface ubuntu-overlay-scrollbars` set to `true` and `org.gnome.desktop.interface ubuntu-overlay-scrollbars` is set to `overlay-auto`. It makes no difference if I switch it to `overlay-pointer`, `overlay-touch` or `normal`. The packages `liboverlay-scrollbar-0.2-0` and `liboverlay-scrollbar3-0.2-0` are not available because they have been replaced with `overlay-scrollbar-gtk2` and `overlay-scrollbar-gtk3` and these are the ones I have installed.

Comment: Maybe you could ask here: https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/xubuntu-users

Comment: vasa1, thank you, but I have figured out the answer - see my post below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the main reason why overlay scrollbars didn't work is because I have configured my system to boot to console first. I then use a custom `.xinitrc` script to start xfce:

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
    xfce4) 
        xscreensaver -no-splash &
        exec ck-launch-session xfce4-session
        ;;
    awesome) 
        exec awesome
        ;;
esac
```

For some reason, when I used the command `xinit xfce4` under Xubuntu 12.04 and previous versions, the overlay scrollbars appeared. However, it seems that 12.10 doesn't load this GTK module, so I had to manually execute this line `declare -x GTK_MODULES="overlay-scrollbar"`. I ended up adding it to my `.bashrc` file so that I don't have to type it every time.

I got this idea from the `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/81overlay-scrollbar` file which says:

```
# This file is sourced by Xsession(5), not executed.

if [ -z "$GTK_MODULES" ] ; then
    GTK_MODULES="overlay-scrollbar"
else
    GTK_MODULES="$GTK_MODULES:overlay-scrollbar"
fi
```

so I guess that this file used to be executed on each start of the X windows syst, but now it isn't used because the `GTK_MODULES` variable wasn't set after start.